# Python bigquery - ImportError: No module named google.apputils

Tags: python, import, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I am trying to use the google bigquery python library but whenever I run `import bq` I get the following error;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-923a4eec0450> in <module>()
----> 1 import bq

/Users/tahirfayyaz/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bq.py in      <module>()
     31 import oauth2client.tools
     32 
---> 33 from google.apputils import app
     34 from google.apputils import appcommands
     35 import gflags as flags

ImportError: No module named google.apputils
```

I have installed and even upgraded google-apputils but I still get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Google Cloud tools are distributed has changed a bit, you'll be able to download a current version of the software via the Cloud SDK:
* https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/

The SDK will install a hermetic environment that contains bigquery as well as all of it's dependencies, like oauth2client and google.apputils. It doesn't use ez-install anymore.

You can add the SDK to your PATH to pick up the current bq.py program.
export PATH=$SDKROOT/platform/bigquery:$PATH

You can add the SDK to your PYTHONPATH if you're trying to import something directly as in your example above.
export PYTHONPATH=$SDKROOT/platform/bigquery:$PYTHONPATH

Comment: I ended up updating anaconda using `conda update conda` and then installed google.apputils again.

I then restarted iPython notebook and that seemed to get it all working.

Thanks for the comments